# How to Control Location of Parallel / GroupBy Stage in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm building an ElasticSearch output for Google Cloud Dataflow that is scalable and does not put load on the ES cluster (batch data flow). My idea for this is to have the nodes of the Dataflow pipeline join the ES cluster and perform the indexing themselves without putting any additional load on the main ES cluster. Therefore I have a stage in the pipeline that on start of the bundle creates a ES node that joins the cluster and then indexes every item that is passed to it itself (via routing settings).

There are two questions that I have to make this work

1. How can I make sure that each bundle is started on a different node? I want in the end one bundle per node, otherwise I have too many shards for ES.
2. What is the best way to create a fixed number of bundles and split work between them? I'm currently doing a group by key based on a random number between 1 and n to create the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Your needs seem closely related to [BEAM-68](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-68), which is a feature specifically targeting the use case of writing to a service without overwhelming it. Today, using a `GroupByKey` like you describe is the usual way to manually shard your input data and limit the number of concurrent writes.

As to your more detailed questions: the particular bundles into which Dataflow splits your data, and distributing those to workers, is chosen by the service, tuned for performance. Even though you can't (and shouldn't try to) control bundling directly, the `GroupByKey` partitions your data into indivisible elements 1 through n, and the number of non-empty bundles cannot be greater than the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks, the request seems to go in the same direction. I'm still testing the groupByKey and if I can see a pattern on the distribution that assigns two groups to the same node.